# GitHub Actions, duplicate check for different trigger events

Tags: github, github-actions

My GitHub Actions workflow gets triggered during these two specified events - when the PR title gets edited and when a code-reviewer submits a review:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [edited]
    branches:
    - master
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
    branches:
    - master
```

Assuming I accept the code changes for the PR, the workflow runs with event: **pull_request_review**

[image]

Then, I change the PR title. The same workflow runs but a new status check is added for event: **pull_request** Now, there are two status checks for the same workflow.

[image]

Is there a way to have only one status check for both events?

Comment: As you performed 2 actions here (code review + title update), 2 different events have triggered the same workflow. If you trigger a workflow with different events, it will always display this way to check which event started the operation and allow traceability. To have only one status, you would need to have only one trigger option.

Comment: @GuiFalourd But in case you track the pull_request and push triggers, only one status check shall display for the PR.

Comment: Oh, I think I understood now. You want to know why the workflow triggered simultaneously for both triggered reasons when you updated the title, instead of having triggered only for the `pull_request edited` event.